# flutter crashlytics dashboard not showing

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, crashlytics

[image]

-------For app level------

```
   dependencies {

implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.3.1')
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics")
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
```

-------For project level------

```
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}

WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp();
FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterFatalError;
PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError = (error, stack) {
FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stack, fatal: true);
return true;
};
```

added all possible things but still dashboard is not showing

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have the necessary import latest for FirebaseCrashlytics:
the verify your main function include the proper setup for runZonedGuarded:

````
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
 runZonedGuarded(() {
    runApp(MyApp());
  }, (error, stackTrace) {
    FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stackTrace);
  });

  FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError;
}```

 


Ensure that you have added the necessary dependencies in your pubspec.yaml file replace with latest :>>>
dependencies:
 ` firebase_core: ^2.17.0
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.3.7`
````

Comment: yes i am adding updated dependencies but still issue not resolving

Comment: tried but still nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens with Crashlytics dashboard. happens with me too.

you should give a try by crashing your app for multiple time.

Also, please add `firebase_crashlytics: ^3.3.4 (latest)`.

Comment: already added latest firebase_crashlytics: ^3.3.7

Comment: is that worked?

Comment: Also, have you added, 
FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);

Comment: yes but still didnt resolve